# Node js can not retrive data from mongodb on remote system

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, mongodb

I am learning node js from this article 
http://cwbuecheler.com/web/tutorials/2014/restful-web-app-node-express-mongodb/

I've developed this app on a remote linux system through xshell (ip - 10.10.30.42).

When I access ( with address `http://10.10.30.42:3000` )the express server from my system in browser it displays no data from mongodb on page but it displays my express design.

I've changed my bind ip to `0.0.0.0` in etc/mongodb.conf but it was no help.

```
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var monk = require('monk');
var db = monk('localhost:27017/nodetest2');
```

[mongod server running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USXw4.png)

Comment: The connection string is looking at `localhost`. Is the MongoDB server instance running on the same machine as the http server or a different one. If it's different then use the remote address. Is there in fact any MongoDB server at all? Also no code here to show you actually trying to retrieve any data.

Comment: mongodb is running on same server. You can look for the whole code in link. I can still provide the code you asked me to if you want . - @NeilLunn